# Размер файла .zip при записи

Tags: java, zip

Принцип части программы такой: записывается некоторая информация в архив с именем, например, `"info0001.zip"`, с помощью `ZipOutputStream`. Имя файла `ZipEntry`, соответственно, `"info0001.xml"`. Если размер архива превысил 1 MB, то создается новый с именем `"info0002.zip"`. Чтобы узнать размер файла, можно вызвать метод `new File("info0001.zip").length()`. Но пока не закроется `ZipOutputStream`, реальный размер файла метод `length()` не вернет. Отрывки из кода:

```
ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("info0001.zip")));
zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("info0001.xml"));

// Некоторая запись в архив 50 мб
// ...

int l = new File("info0001.zip").length(); // l = 49 байт
```

Если закрыть архив перед вызовом `length`, то размер будет верный.

Но мне нужно дальше писать в этот архив.

Долго рылся в реализации класса `ZipOutputStream`, и нашел:
класс `ZipOutputStream` наследуется от `DeflaterOutputStream`, который содержит:

```
protected Deflater def;
```

В этом объекте в методе `deflate` и происходит архивация. Там происходит подсчет записанных байтов, и его можно возвратить с помощью метода `getBytesRead()`.
Был создан класс:

```
public class MyZipOutputStream extends ZipOutputStream {

    public MyZipOutputStream(OutputStream out) {
        super(out);
    }

    public long size() {
        return super.def.getBytesRead();
    }
}
```

Но ждал жестокий облом, `size()` возвращает размер файла без архивации.
Так как же узнать размер архива без его закрытия?

Comment: А почему вы используете `getBytesRead()`? Ведь логичнее было бы использовать `getBytesWritten()` или вовсе `getTotalOut()` для определения размера результирующего zip-файла. А `getBytesRead()` — это, как вы сами заметили, да и как следует из названия, метод получения количества *прочитанных* байт, то есть как раз размер исходных файлов.

Comment: А если сделать:  

    zout.flush();

перед `length()` ?

Comment: getBytesWritten() возвращает 0, несмотря на то, сколько я запишу в архив